# Write to a matrix in .oct file without looping?

Tags: c++, matrix, octave

In an Octave .oct file it is possible to extract a submatrix thus:

```
B = A.extract(a-1,c-1,b-1,d-1) ;
```

the equivalent of B = A(a:b,c:d) in Octave code, but is it possible to write to a subset of a matrix in a similar manner,

```
A(a-1,c-1,b-1,d-1) = B ; // some other smaller matrix
```

or would I have to loop over the relevant rows/columns and write element by element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `A` is of class `Array`, you can use one of the following methods (see [the documentation](http://octave.sourceforge.net/doxygen/html/d0/d26/classArray.html)):

```
Array<T> & insert (const Array<T> &a, octave_idx_type r, octave_idx_type c)
Array<T> & insert (const Array<T> &a, const Array<octave_idx_type> &idx)
```

You only need to know the subscript index for the top left corner (or its equivalent for N dimensions). The following will insert the 2D matrix `B` into the 2D matrix `A`, at coordinates `(a, c)`

```
A.insert (B, a, c);
```

For more dimensions, you'll need to create an `Array<octave_idx_type>` with coordinates for that point.

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to do is more like A.index (idx_vector (a, b), idx_vector (c, c)) = B ; i.e. I have a large zero filled matrix A and I want to insert into A a smaller matrix B.

Comment: @babelproofreader you are right. I misread your question. I have updated the answer.